# Strange behavior cordova plugin

Tags: javascript, android, cordova

I have a problem with a plugin for [`cordova`](https://github.com/christocracy/cordova-plugin-background-geolocation)

When I use the plugin on android 4.4 it works perfectly but when I try it on android 4.2 it doesn't work the first time. After reloading the application it works, on second reload stops working again.

The error is:

```
      TypeError: Cannot read property 'backgroundGeoLocation' of undefined
```

Any ideas?

Regards

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem.
It's just that the plugin isn't ready at this time.

Do not forget to put the initialization code in the onDeviceReady function!

```
document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);
function onDeviceReady() {
    ... 
}
```